# invalid trigger error

Tags: oracle

I have a table "paciente" with "tipo_quarto" and i need a trigger that everytime I insert something in "tipo_quarto" the table "quarto" update the "tipo".

Here is the function/trigger

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADD_PACIENTE_QUARTO
  (CONT IN VARCHAR Default Null)
  RETURN VARCHAR
 IS 
  PAC VARCHAR; 

BEGIN 
  Select TIPO_QUARTO into PAC from PACIENTE
  Where PAC = CONT;

  return PAC;

END ADD_PACIENTE_QUARTO;

create or replace TRIGGER PACIENTE_TRIGGER

  AFTER 
  INSERT OR UPDATE  
  ON TIPO_QUARTO 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  Declare 
  PAC VARCHAR;
  BEGIN

  PAC:=ADD_PACIENTE_QUARTO(:new.TIPO_QUARTO);

  If :new.TIPO_QUARTO = 'UTI' then
   PAC := PAC - :new.TIPO;
   else
   PAC := PAC + :new.TIPO;
  End If;

  UPDATE TIPO_QUARTO SET TIPO = PAC
    WHERE TIPO = :new.TIPO;
  END;
```

here are the table's;

PACIENTE

```
  CREATE TABLE PACIENTE 
(
PRIMEIRO_NOME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
SEGUNDO_NOME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CPF NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
IDADE NUMBER(3)NOT NULL,
SEXO VARCHAR(1)NOT NULL,
TIPO_QUARTO VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PACIENTE_PK PRIMARY KEY(CPF)
);
```

TIPO_QUARTO

```
CREATE TABLE TIPO_QUARTO
(TIPO VARCHAR(3)NOT NULL,
PACIENTE_CPF NUMBER(11)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT TIPO_QUARTO PRIMARY KEY (TIPO),
CONSTRAINT TIPO_QUARTO_FK FOREIGN KEY(PACIENTE_CPF) REFERENCES PACIENTE(CPF)
);
```

Comment: You have tagged this with sql server but the code looks a lot like Oracle and nothing like sql server.

Comment: Table's structure (`paciente` and `quarto`) would be appreciated as well as a test case of the process you want to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'll post this as an answer because comments won't allow this much text.

Seeing your tables some things still aren't clear. your function `ADD_PACIENTE_QUARTO` implements a `SELECT` statement which states the predicate `Where PAC = CONT` but `PAC` isn't in `PACIENTE`'s specification but rather is the local variable where you store your result and `CONT` is your parameter, it's not clear what you tried there.

Now your trigger has some flaws in logic and implementation.

First of all, your trigger's name is `PACIENTE_TRIGGER` but the line `INSERT OR UPDATE ON TIPO_QUARTO` tells me it's on the `TIPO_QUARTO` table, this is not a problem syntactically but logically can be a pain in the butt for someone who's trying to figure out to which table the trigger belongs.

Next, use `INSERT OR UPDATE OF TIPO ON TIPO_QUARTO` to monitor Inserts or update changes **only** in column `TIPO` of `TIPO_QUARTO` table.

Now this line `If :new.TIPO_QUARTO = 'UTI' then`, assuming this trigger is attached to `TIPO_QUARTO` table,  that table does not have a column named `TIPO_QUARTO` change this to `:new.TIPO`.

Next, `PAC` is of type `VARCHAR` so it's unclear to me what are you trying to do in `PAC := PAC - :new.TIPO;` and in `PAC := PAC + :new.TIPO;` both lines will throw `invalid number` exception as you can't add or subtract strings, maybe your intention was to concatenate or to get a sub string.

And lastly the call to `UPDATE TIPO_QUARTO SET TIPO = PAC` inside a trigger for `TIPO_QUARTO` will result in `mutating table` exception, you can't query/update a table that's in the middle of a DML statement (INSERT or UPDATE in this case) to fix this you can just assign `:new.TIPO := PAC`.

Take care of this details and maybe then your problem won't be no more.