# Trigger not updating table

Tags: oracle

I have this function/trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CARRINHO_SALDO
  (CAR IN Number Default Null)
  RETURN Number
 IS 
  SALD Number; 

BEGIN 
  Select SALDO into SALD from CARRINHO_COMPRA
  Where CONTA = CAR;

  return SALD;

END CARRINHO_SALDO;

create or replace TRIGGER EFETUAR_COMPRA_TRIGGER
  AFTER 
  INSERT OR UPDATE  
  ON EFETUAR_CARRINHO_COMPRA 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  Declare 
  SALD Number;
  BEGIN

  SALD:=CARRINHO_SALDO(:new.CONTA);

  If :new.COMPRA = 'c' then
   SALD := SALD - :new.VALOR;
   else
   SALD := SALD + :new.VALOR;
  End If;

  UPDATE CARRINHO_COMPRA SET SALDO = SALD
    WHERE CONTA = :new.CONTA;
  END;
```

its supose to work like;everytime I add something in "EFETUAR_CARRINHO_COMPRA"table the table CARRINHO_COMPRA have to update the "saldo".I do the insert correctly

```
  INSERT INTO EFETUAR_CARRINHO_COMPRA(conta,id_compra,compra,valor,data) VALUES(2,616,'c',1000,'30-06-2017');
```

The table "EFETUAR_CARRINHO_COMPRA" updates ok.but the table CARRINHO_COMPRA dont get the values that is supose to update from the insert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid trigger error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850835/invalid-trigger-error)

Comment: I agree with @JairHernandez that these two questions seem similar. Please don't post duplicate questions. It disrespects the people trying to help you and pollutes the site with unnecessary noise. If you don't get the answer you want **edit your original question** to make it better and to address the points raised.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't already a row in `CARRINHO_COMPRA` for `CONTA` = 2 the first time the trigger is invoked, the trigger will fail because the `Select SALDO into SALD from CARRINHO_COMPRA` in your `CARRINHO_SALDO` procedure will throw a NO_DATA_FOUND exception, which isn't trapped anywhere. You might try revising `CARRINHO_SALDO` to trap the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception and deal with it reasonably:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CARRINHO_SALDO
    (CAR IN Number Default Null)
  RETURN Number
IS 
  SALD Number; 
BEGIN 
  BEGIN
    Select SALDO
      into SALD from CARRINHO_COMPRA
      Where CONTA = CAR;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      SALD := 0;
  END;

  return SALD;
END CARRINHO_SALDO;
```

Best of luck.